# Triple integral: $\iiint_W\ dx\ dy\ dz$ where $W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2 \le r^2\}$

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to solve the following triple integral using spherical coordinates:

$$\iiint_W\ dx\ dy\ dz$$
where
$$W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2 \le r^2\}$$

What I've tried:

After drafting the region it appears to me that:
$$
0 \le r \le \ ? \\
0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \le \phi \le 2\pi
$$

But I am not sure how to convert the equation of the region to spherical coordinates and to determine the value of $r$.

Are my determinations correct? How do i proceed?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788308/where-does-this-formula-for-the-volume-of-a-n-dimensional-ball-come-from/1788320#1788320 (case $n=3$).

Comment: You have one mistake, it should be $0\le\theta\le\pi$. And you should use a constant $R$ instead of the $?$. After this just put those into $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^R\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this problem, $r$ is not a variable, but a parameter, like $\pi$, except we don't know what it is, the variable $r$, the distance from the origin, will be between $0$ and the parameter $r$, it helps if you change the parameter $r$ to $d$ for distance from origin or something else

Also note that $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ since $\theta$ must encompass the entire circle while $\phi $ must go from axis to axis, half a circle

Comment: Isn't axis to axis a 90 degree angle?

Comment: @OmariCelestine, well the $z^+$ axis to anything but the $z^-$ axis is but $z^+\to z^-=\pi$

Comment: Oh, yea. Now I realize.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing letters. If I was you, I would have written

$$W=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2 \le R^2\right\}$$

so

$$0\leq r\leq R$$

Also, note that you should have

$$0\leq\theta\leq\pi$$

The angles are defined in the following sketch

[image]

Comment: theta is to $2\pi$ and phi is to $\pi$

Comment: @JacobClaassen We seem to use different definitions. Usually $\theta$ is the azimuth angle and $\varphi$ is the angle in the $\rm XY$ plane. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system.

Comment: @eraneches I'm in the class right now and I'm being taught the opposite. I'm also being taught that it's rho and not $r$ to distinguish it from cylindrical coordinates. Also that page shows both...

Comment: @JacobClaassen This is just a convention. You can use either $\rho$ or $r$. Some people prefer the former and some the latter. The same goes with $\theta$ and $\varphi$. This really doesn't matter as long as you remain consistent in your calculations. Anyway, I added a sketch of the coordinates to prevent confusion.